# How to verify the Gird to List and List to Grid functionality in Cypress

Tags: cypress

We have View functionality that a user can able to change based on his/her requirement.

A user can change a view Gird To List and List to Gird view.

By default view in Grid view.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Can you add the HTML of the grid, as well as any Cypress code you've written to try and solve the problem? Also, what problem are you trying to solve? From your description, it just sounds like you have a grid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @agoff,  Actually, yet not implemented code logic as I am not sure about which approach I can go for it.

I am having dashboard and its has some details. We have functionality that a user can change the view of dashboard. We have two time of view first one is List View and second one is Grid view. 

<table _ngcontent-qvc-c145="" mat-table="" matsort="" class="mat-table cdk-table mat-sort mat-elevation-z8" role="grid">
  <thead role="rowgroup">
</thead/
</table>